# gave same time on converting Date.now()

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for something to convert exact time

```js
var arr = [1585287883,1585287876,1585287736,1585287730,1585287725,1585287720];
arr.forEach(val=>{
    console.log(Date(val).toString())
})
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: This code gave same output in loop. but actually it should gave different time

Comment: those values are milliseconds apart

Comment: @ashmitmittal you forgot to put `new`,  new Date(val).toString()

Comment: @JaromandaX they are *seconds* apart. They have to be converted to milliseconds

Comment: `console.log(new Date(val).toISOString())` - you'll see the times range from ....21:27.720 to ...21:27.883 ... all within 100 ms

Comment: @VLAZ - that's one possibility :p

Comment: answer is given by 2 person, both are correct, up vote it :)

Comment: @ashmitmittal If you don't know in what precision your input values are given, you could define a small helper function and use it to convert to milliseconds first. Something like `const to_milliseconds = (val) => {
    while ((val % 1000000000000) === val) { val = val * 10; };
    return val;
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with what you posted:

1. `Date` -> `new Date`
2. The timestamps in javascript should represent milliseconds, currently they represent seconds. You can multiply the timestamps by `1000` when building the date object, to convert seconds to milliseconds.

```js
var arr = [1585287883,1585287876,1585287736,1585287730,1585287725,1585287720];
arr.forEach(val=>{
    console.log(new Date(val*1000).toString())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that you're using the wrong input format. Instead of seconds since 1970-01-01, you should use milliseconds.

> A JavaScript date is fundamentally specified as the number of
>   milliseconds that have elapsed since midnight on January 1, 1970, UTC.
>   This date and time is the same as the UNIX epoch, which is the
>   predominant base value for computer-recorded date and time values.
>
> Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Simply, multiply you're input by 1000 (and use the keyword new ;) )

```js
var arr = [1585287883,1585287876,1585287736,1585287730,1585287725,1585287720];
arr.forEach(val=>{
    console.log(new Date(val * 1000).toString());
})
```